# Display nested Json in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular. I am trying to display Json object in component. I am using `keyvalue` pipe with `*ngFor` to achieve this.

My Json Object

```js
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Delivery"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Dine-out"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Nightlife"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Catching-up"
      }
    },
    {
      "categories": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Takeaway"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My Component HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let obcategories of users | keyvalue">
    <div *ngFor="let obcategory of obcategories.value | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let nestedobcategory of obcategory.value | keyvalue">
            {{nestedobcategory.value}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is displaying all both `id` value and `name` value. I want to display only `name` value.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON is not matching with `*ngFor` keys, values.

Comment: Try directly with `{{obcategory.name}}` and remove the 3rd nested `*ngFor`.

Comment: hi, your code is good enough  you just use {{nestedobcategory.value.name}} instead of {{nestedobcategory.value}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{{nestedobcategory.value.name}}` to access the name property:

```
<div *ngFor="let obcategories of users | keyvalue">
    <div *ngFor="let obcategory of obcategories.value | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let nestedobcategory of obcategory.value | keyvalue">
            {{nestedobcategory.value.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdp9e2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I was breaking my head till now.  Thanks a  lot your solution works like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome. Just a tip, if you see something is not printing, try with `{{nestedobcategory.value | json}}` you will get a clear picture of what is happening. And kindly upvote if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
{{ nestedobcategory.value }}
```

To:

```
{{ nestedobcategory.value.name }}
```

Code after changes:

```
<div *ngFor="let nestedobcategory of obcategory.value | keyvalue">
      {{ nestedobcategory.value.name }}
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-rfekw2?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

A minor change would be:

`nestedobcategory.value` **=>** `nestedobcategory.value.name`

**IMP :** In such cases use [`JsonPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) just to check what object you getting. If you use

```
{{ nestedobcategory.value | json }}
```

It will display your objects in the JSON Structure *(Key/Value pair)* and then you can access values that you want to display on the HTML.